# Why "select unix_timestamp('') is null" returns false when "select unix_timestamp('')" returns null?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 1.6.2 and trying to find if a field contains empty string or a date value.

[Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#unix_timestamp(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) explains that if unix_timestamp() function returns null if it fails so below behaviour is expected:

```
sqlContext.sql("select unix_timestamp('')").show
+----+
| _c0|
+----+
|null|
+----+
```

But when I try to check it with "is null" it returns false:

```
sqlContext.sql("select unix_timestamp('') is null").show
+-----+
|  _c0|
+-----+
|false|
+-----+
```

Same query returns true in Hive:

```
hive> select unix_timestamp('') is null;
OK
true
```

Here is null checking on null for the sake of completeness:

```
sqlContext.sql("select null is null").show
+----+
| _c0|
+----+
|true|
+----+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug and it looks like it has been already resolved in Spark 2.x branch (probably with [SPARK-12054](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12054)) The source of the problem is schema returned by the `unix_timestamp`. If you execute:

```
sqlContext.sql("select unix_timestamp('')").printSchema
```

you'll see:

```
root
 |-- _c0: long (nullable = false)
```

Since schema is reported as not `nullable` values are not checked and and `unix_timestamp(...).isNull` is always false.